# Given 2 linear functions a and c that intersect at point B. At the point B, a new circle with given radius. Contruct an orthogonal circle.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQvEy.png)

- The full problem: Given 2 linear functions a and c that always intersect at point B. At the point B, draw a circle b with given radius which intersect line a at point A and line c at point C. Construct a new circle that is orthogonal to circle b and go through point A, B.

NOTE: This problem is not hard to solve manually but I have to write a program to solve it that require the least amount of computational power AKA optimization.

Here's an exapmle of this problem.

Assign:

- Line a: **y=-x-1**
- Line c: **y=2x+5**

I can easily compute the point **B (-2,1)**

Assume the radius is $\sqrt{2}$, I have the function for cirlce b: $(x+2)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 2$

From here, we just need to find thefunction of  the new circle, let's call it $(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = R^2$

If  I have to solve it manually, I will go with this method:

- Called the center of the circle D then apply pythagorean theorem: $AD^2 + AB^2 = DB^2$
- Line AB is perpendicular to line AD so the slope of line AB * Slope of line AD = -1

If I expand the two equations I have a set of 2 equations with 2 variables:  $=x_0, y_0$

But since I have to write a program to solve it with the least amount of computational power. I would love to find other method of solving this.

Answer (score 1):

[image: OrthogonalCircle]

We hope that you can slightly reduce the number of computation by using the following geometric construction.

You have not mentioned anything about determining the coordinates of the points of intersections $A$ and $C$ of the first circle with the two given lines. But it is obvious that you have to do those calculations before applying the Pythagoras’ theorem.

After obtaining the coordinates of the points $A$ and $C$, instead of applying Pythagoras’ theorem, you could easily find the equations of the two lines $AD$ and $CD$, because they are perpendicular to $BA$ and $BC$ respectively. The center of the circle, which is orthogonal to the first circle, is the point of intersection of $AD$ and $CD$. As you can see, you still have to solve a system of equations that has two equations, but they are linear.